# Изображения растягиваются по высотке на IOS и добавляется отступ, в чем проблема?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Постоянно сталкиваюсь с проблемой того, что на всех устройствах кроме IOS изображения по высотке встают нормально, а на IOS занимают места, чем должны. Визуально они остаются со своими пропорциями, но образуется непонятный отступ.
Самое банальное решение в media задаваться max-height, но на мой взгляд это костыльное решение и я уверен есть способы решить данную проблему, только не могу понять как...
modno.uniqcode.ru/model.html
Вот пример верстки, на всех устройствах изображения сохраняют свои пропорции без ненужных отступов, но IOS выдает следующую картину:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

У тебя в **.s_publications .row a** явно не задана высота, вот сафари и растягивает как ему хочется. А из-за того, что у картинки object-fit: contain, она растягивается по ширине на 100%, а высоту считает автоматически.

Поставь высоту ссылке, всё заработает.
Также советую почитать https://proglib.io/p/responsive-images/ для работы с изображениями. Там есть пару хаков, поможет.

Comment: Привет, спасибо за ответ, в целом я понял, но из за того что изображения занимают условно говоря по 30% ширины, их высота меняется и получается я не могу задать высоту там ровно 100px
На сколько правильно будет например привязаться к VW подобрать и поставить её на несколько media запросов и менять когда кол-во изображений в ряд уменьшается?

Comment: я прикрепила статью, посмотри там пример с паддингами (решение от netflix, когда картинка абсолютом). Оно тебе поможет сохранить пропорции.

И решение с vw + медиазапросы мне кажется правильным

Comment: и обращай внимание на object-fit. Он может тебе всё портить. Лучше сделай его cover